# Load Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I need to change views programmatically.

My storyboard:

[image]

When the app launchs,Login view controller loads.But I need to load `Tab Bar Controller` from `Login View Controller's` `viewDidLoad()` method.How can I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24365283/3411191

Comment: Yes,I was found that question but,I don't have specific class for tab bar controller.So what should I put for "as BillInfoViewController" ?

Comment: You could use `let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("billInfo")` to create a Tab Bar Controller instance assuming you set your storyboard ID to "billinfo". But feel free to change the Storyboard ID.

Comment: 2015-03-27 02:14:01.461 Ribony[1887:1373596] Warning: Attempt to present <UITabBarController: 0x7fa2e95550b0> on <Ribony.LoginViewController: 0x7fa2e942ea60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

What should I do now ?

Comment: What method are you using to present the UITabBarController?

Comment: What do you mean ? You mean segue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73885/discussion-between-zane-helton-and-okan).