# How do I transition to a different view controllers present in different storyboards programmatically using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

```
let customerStoryboard =   UIStoryboard(name: "Customer", bundle: nil) //First(Current) storyboard 
let agentStoryboard =   UIStoryboard(name: "Agent", bundle: nil)  //Second storyboard

var otherVC = UIViewController!   // ViewController reference

otherVC = agentStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AgentProfile")
```

The last statement is not executing or showing results, is anything else required to do other than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only instantiate view controller. To present it you should use [presentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) method

```
someVC.presentViewController(otherVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to show the second view controller.

```
let otherVC : AnyObject! = self.agentStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AgentProfile")
self.showViewController(otherVC as UIViewController, sender: otherVC)
```

Comment: See this question for further reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336581/programmatically-switching-views-swift

Comment: can i use the above same code to switch between view controllers of same storyboard

Comment: @ Julian E.--- how can otherVC be sender in second argument

Comment: the sender here must be the destination vc. You could consult this SO answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336581/programmatically-switching-views-swift

Comment: showViewController(otherVC as UIViewController, sender: otherVC)      ---------hides my navigation bar in the next view controller is there any way to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController

self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: @ RKP this is the error i get while using above code----- fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value